Cannot access Firebird database with Docker Node + Express container application when it is running on the same Linux machine as the database
This Node + Express application that communicates with databases using the node-firebird library connects to multiple databases, some on a Linux server and others on another. The code was always able to connect to the databases on both servers, in the test environment on my personal computer and in production on the Render platform. However, I recently moved the application to work on the server where some of the databases are located. From there, it can access the databases on the other server, but it cannot connect to the databases on the server itself, returning:
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT (serverIp):(firebirdPort)
I already tried changing the path to the database to access it locally, but it failed too.
Detail: The Firebird database is running directly on the server, not in a container.

Have you checked if the server is accepting connections on the port and IP address you're trying to connect to?

Yes it's accepting, how i said, the application can connect to this adress when running in my personal computer and on render.

OK, but what is that IP address? For example, 127.0.0.1 inside a docker container refers to the container, not to the host machine.

Is the IPV4 in the web of the VPS, like "123.432.23.12".

That is probably not accessible from the Docker container itself, see From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?
